# Clear and Best Approach for CRUD operation in android studio for beginners

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am learning android development and start with Johnny Manson youtube videos to create basic CRUD application.

On part 6 he select image from gallery and set ImageView URI. every think same as in video but my ImageView set Blank when i select image from gallery??

```
    _ContactImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Contact Image"), 1);
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data){
    if (resCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (reqCode == 1)
            _ContactImage.setImageURI(data.getData()); // I reach here when i Debug
    }
```

logcat when use bitmap solution

```
10-16 23:22:02.668  15504-15504/com.example.solutionwares.contactmanager E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.solutionwares.contactmanager, PID: 15504
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/67 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.solutionwares.contactmanager/com.example.solutionwares.contactmanager.MyActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/67 from pid=15504, uid=10252 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3551)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3594)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1313)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/67 from pid=15504, uid=10252 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:148)
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:682)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1066)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:907)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:632)
            at com.example.solutionwares.contactmanager.MyActivity.onActivityResult(MyActivity.java:117)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5618)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3547)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3594)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1313)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

SOLVED by simply add permission in Manifest

```
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: what is _ContactImage? An ImageView?

Comment: yes _ContactImage is ImageView

Comment: _ContactImage.setImageURI(data.getData()); // I reach here when i Debug

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below instead. The reason for this suggestion, is that there is some note in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) about using [setImageURI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)) that might cause hiccups...

UPDATE, sample onClick:

```
_ContactImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.setType("image/*");
     intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
     startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
    }
});

private Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
    if (reqCode== 1 && resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        try {

            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }

            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    data.getData());
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();
            _ContactImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);
 }

}
```

Comment: where does it crash? any logcats?